# Как изменить стиль текста до первой точки?

Tags: javascript, css, css3

есть строка с датой, допустим, "12.10.2016", и надо изменить стиль первых двух цифр, то есть **12** что бы получилось "**12**.10.2016"

как это можно реализовать?

дата находится в отдельном блоке, но кроме неё там еще может быть написано вместо даты "СЕГОДНЯ, 18:00", "ЗАВТРА, 05:32" и "ВЧЕРА". так что надо изменить стиль именно до точки, а не просто первые две цифры

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:

```js
let string = "12.10.2016".replace(/^(\d+)\./, "<span>$1</span>.");

console.log(string);
```

`span` уже соответственно стилизовать, как хочется.